# Elements of a Negative Semidefinite Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Use the definition of a negative definite matrix to show that if A is negative semi-definite:

$$A_{ii} ≤ 0 \ \forall i $$

I know the definition (in terms of quadratic form) and the equivalent rules (principal minors, eigenvalues, etc) but I can't seem to get this proof out! I'm not even quite sure why the question suggests using the definition of a negative definite matrix, other than the fact negative definite implies negative semi-definite.

Any pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative semi-definite is equivalent to $x^TAx\le 0$ for all $x$. Now, choose the right $x$ to obtain the desired result.

Comment: Do we just consider x = [1 0 0 0 0 0 . . .], x = [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 . . .] and so on?

Comment: Exactly, use $x=e_i$, with $e_i$ being the $i$-th unit vector